# Magento 2: Is it possible to update order by customer after placing it?

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order

> After placing an order, is it the possible customer can manually update
>   order Qty or delete an item from order?

Comment: No. By user I understand a customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box, Magento does not allow a customer to edit order on frontend side, once an order has been placed It can change by only on order status. But on admin level magento allow this feature with certain limitation. Like you can change only `Billing Address` and `Shipping Address`. But without calculating a shipping price.

[image]

And whenever when you try to edit customer order in backend Magento always create a new order.

[image]

Comment: is it possible by custom module to develop this functionality?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. but you need to do lots of work if your customer using some online payment method and you allow changing qty and item. @Bhavik

Answer (score 0):

If you are refering "User" as a customer then by default it is not possible but the customer can reorder/cancel the order.
And if the user is "admin" then yes,he can do what he want with the order.